# CSS beginner, background image won't show up

Tags: html, css, background-image

My background-image won't show up. Do I need to tag the image in the HTML? Maybe position reference or something? Please help!

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="sespe.css"/>
    <title>Sespe Pizza Co.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header1">
        <h1>Sespe Pizza Co.</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="mb1"></div>
    <div id="mb2"></div>
    <div id="mb3"></div>
    <div id="mainPage">

    <div id="b1"></div>
    <div id="b2"></div>
    <div id="b3"></div>
    <div id="b4"></div>
    <div id="b5"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS.....

```css
body {
    background-image:         url('/Users/Username/Downloads/3634195609_f6b7edac1b_b.jpg'); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your path is the problem. You are navigating to your downloads folder. Place your image in a folder in your site folder, call it say 'images' and then call it into your css like this. If your new 'images' folder is on the same level as your css folder, the first option would work. `../`because you are going up one folder to get to `images`.

```
body {
  background-image: url('../images/3634195609_f6b7edac1b_b.jpg');
}
```

Edit: Seems in your case, your css file is not in a css folder, so you can just get to your images folder without going to a different level:

```
body {
  background-image: url('images/3634195609_f6b7edac1b_b.jpg');
}
```

Comment: @rainman0915 No problem, glad it worked out. Don't forget to accept the answer.