# How to set the background image with Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<div class="class1">
    <app-home></app-home>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div><div class="class1">
    <app-home></app-home>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div> <!-- This is the home.component.heml -->


.class1{
    background-image: url(/Users/md.nuhelnawazchowdhury/Desktop/Shoppie/andalib/src/assets/img/Shoppie1.jpeg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I can't get the home page to show the background image. The files above are app.component files.

Comment: Url should be in quotes shouldn't it?

Comment: I tried to add the image in the home.component.html and also tried the home.component.css. It only showed the "Home works! text.

Comment: Is the image path correct?

Comment: Your path is outside the webroot, that will never work. Just start from ‘assets/..’

Comment: Try with ngStyle!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS beginner, background image won't show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791372/css-beginner-background-image-wont-show-up)

Answer (score 4):

First start by putting your images inside `assets` folder.
`Assets` folder is automatically created by Angular CLI, when you create a new project.
Now it depends on where you wanna use the background image.
If you are in app folder you can do somthing like this:

```
background-image: url(../assets/Shoppie1.jpeg);
```

if you are deeper, say you created a component in its own folder, you will have to do something like:

```
background-image: url(../../assets/Shoppie1.jpeg);
```

I created this github demo if you wanna see how it is done: [link](https://github.com/encetroc/angular-demo)

Answer (score 2):

Yout path should be `/assets/img/Shoppie1.jpeg`

```css
 background-image: url("/assets/img/Shoppie1.jpeg")
```

Open `Developer tools > Network` tab and check if the image is getting downloaded while the app is loaded.

Comment: I tried that. Now, the image is only a black bar on the top.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a url in single quotation for a url as shown below!

```
<div class="class1">
    <app-home></app-home>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div><div class="class1">
    <app-home></app-home>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div> <!-- This is the home.component.html -->


.class1{
    background-image: url('/Users/md.nuhelnawazchowdhury/Desktop/Shoppie/andalib/src/assets/img/Shoppie1.jpeg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But for the best practice of developing an angular app I would recommend to create a separate folder for images inside an asset folder that would be the best way to track and make an application clean.

Comment: The `url(` and `)` should not be in the quotation marks, only the actual URL.

Comment: I'm not the OP, just someone who knows CSS syntax. Now you have double quotes around the whole thing. There should be no quotes around `url(...)`. See [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

Comment: Thanks! I made it as url ('---');

Comment: I tried the url within the  " ", now it's just a black bar at the top of the page

Comment: Put it in a single quotation not in a double quotation.